# Gale-Shapley – can it be used to find stable friendship?

Tags: algorithms

Can Gale-Shapley be used to find a stable friendship among a group of people who give a list of people they'd like to be friends with?

Could we create a stable and a whole couple of friends?

So lets say we got 4 people and their lists:

A: B, C, D

B: C, D, A

C: D, B, A

D: A, B, C

now A goes first and picks B.

and C goes and picks D.

D and B disagree with the matching.  is this proof by counter example acceptable?

Comment: It's one third of a proof; if you're claiming there's no stable matching, you have to check all $3$ possible matchings. What if you match A with D and B with C? That's stable, isn't it?

Comment: I believe you're asking about the [stable roommates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem) problem. That Wikipedia page has a simple example of a set of lists where no stable matching is possible.

Comment: By the way I couldn't decipher your sentence "Could we create a stable and a whole couple of friends?". Is that a Google Translation from your native language?

Comment: not really, I meant to say that for every person there is a match, ( Whole). and they all agree with the results, (Stable), Probably should've said complete or perfect instead of whole.

Comment: I see. The line begins to make sense if we change "couple" to "matching". A *couple* is just a pair (2 people); a *matching* is a **set** of disjoint pairs; a *perfect matching* is a matching which covers all the vertices (people).

Comment: And "stable" does not mean that "they all agree with the results". For instance, if only one person disagrees, no matter how violently, that does not make the matching unstable. Instability occurs that there are two people, who are not matched with each other, and prefer each other to their current partners.